# Caching MongoDB objects in PHP

Tags: php, caching, mongodb

I've been trying to write "good code" and use dependency injection to pass database objects in the constructors of my classes.

Constructors are generally taking this form:

```
public function __construct(MongoDB $db) {
    $this->collection = $db->collectionName;
}
```

I've noticed that for each object created, a **new** `MongoCollection` is created. (i.e. accessing the  `$db->collectionName` **property** twice returns two distinct objects, not the same object)

I've been using an ActiveRecord style base class, so that objects are able to CRUD themselves.

Now when I use some sort of `getAllRecords()` function, and return 100s of these objects, 100s of `MongoCollection` objects are created. (A quick look at the driver source seems to indicate new objects are created there too, not just new representations in PHP)

I've gotten around this by wrapping both `Mongo` and `MongoDB` classes to implement caching.

```
class MyMongo extends Mongo
{
    private $objectCache = array();

    public function __get($name) {
        return array_key_exists($name, $this->objectCache)
            ? $this->objectCache[$name]
            : $this->objectCache[$name] = new MyMongoDB($this, $name);
    }
}

class MyMongoDB extends MongoDB
{
    private $objectCache = array();

    public function __get($name) {
        return array_key_exists($name, $this->objectCache)
            ? $this->objectCache[$name]
            : $this->objectCache[$name] = new MongoCollection($this, $name);
    }
}
```

My questions are as follows:

- Is this intended behaviour of MongoDB? Should it really be returning a new object each time, or is it a bug/feature in the PHP driver or Mongo itself (is there a use-case for needing 2 objects for the same collection?)
- Will I cause problems for myself by caching either/both `MongoDB` and `MongoCollection` objects that are created, and re-using them.
- How do other people typically handle working with MongoDB? Should I be using a different approach entirely? (I.e. DataMapper)

Thanks,

Leigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's intentional, as collections have properties other than their names associated with them (w and wtimeout at the moment, more planned for the future).  If all you care about are the names, then it's fine to cache them.

Comment: Thanks @kristina, I think any changes I would need to make to w or wtimeout would be the same across all collections, so it appears to just be the name of the collection I care about. May I ask how you typically manage your data objects? Do you use ActiveRecord, DataMapper, something else, or simply whatever seems to fit best?

Comment: I wrote the driver, so my knowledge of it is mostly theoretical :)  Users with more practical experience are probably better qualified to answer the third part of your question.

Comment: I know you wrote the driver, that's why I'm pestering you ;) - But TY for your time, I know there's some guys in the PHP chat who use Mongo, I'll go and bug them.

Answer (score 1):

I've been passing the `MongoCollection` into my objects instead of the `MongoDb`. My reasoning was that choosing the collection in the object would be a hidden dependency (may be overkill) and then in my unit tests, I can mock the `MongoCollection` object.

Comment: My constructors actually have `parent::__construct($db->collection)` in them. *My reasoning* was that an object is fine knowing what it's own collection is, and I didn't want to have to keep track of 100s of collections outside of the object.